# excel format string based on range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2003

So I have column A of long text, in which several names are mentioned. Each cell in the column is a mini-essay of sorts. Some important names are repeated throughout every cell and I need to highlight these names in a different colour. So, a macro that conditionally formats when it finds these names.

I'm able to do that when the names I'm looking for are fixed, but I've been trying to find a way to search a list of names (in Sheet B) so that I can add to this list of names as and when necessary. I've been looking around google and here but I've only found ways to find based on either 1) a specific string of text, or 2) a single cell. I can't figure out how to map the finding to a variable range of cells.

Using Excel 2003.

By name:

```
Sub FormatTest()
Dim g As Range
For Each g In Selection.Cells
    FormatCell g
Next
End Sub


Sub FormatCell(g As Range)
Dim pos1 As Integer, pos2 As Integer
pos1 = 1
pos2 = InStr(pos1, g.Text, "Alicia")
v = Len("Alicia")
pos3 = pos2 + v
g.Characters(Start:=pos2, Length:=pos3 - pos2).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)    
End Sub
```

By cell:

```
Sub FormatTest()
Dim e As Range
For Each e In Selection.Cells
    FormatCell e
Next
End Sub
Sub FormatCell(e As Range)
Dim pos1 As Integer, pos2 As Integer
pos1 = 1
pos2 = InStr(pos1, e.Text, Range("B20"))
v = len(Range("B20"))
pos3 = pos2 + v
e.Characters(Start:=pos2, Length:=pos3 - pos2).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
```

Comment: do you need each name in a different color?

Comment: nope. every name that was on the list, should appear in the cells of column A in the same colour (anything other than black). thank you for reading!

Comment: can you post the code you use with fixed names?

Comment: You can loop through the cells in your list of names, and then through the "essay" cells, using `instr()` to find whether the name is present. If found, you can color the name using (e.g.)  `cell.characters(startPos,length).font.color=vbred`

Comment: @nutsch edited with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This update to your code will do it, but will not work (just like your initial code) if you have multiple instances of the name in one cell. Will that happen?

```
Sub FormatTest()
Dim g As Range, rgWords As Range, rgWord As Range

'turn off updates to speed up code execution
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

'set the range where you keep the list of words you're searching for here:
Set rgWords = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A3")

For Each g In Selection.Cells
    For Each rgWord In rgWords.Cells
        if len(rgWord)>0 then FormatCell g, rgWord.Text
    Next rgWord
Next

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With

End Sub


Sub FormatCell(g As Range, sWord As String)
Dim pos1 As Integer, pos2 As Integer
pos1 = 1
pos2 = InStr(pos1, g.Text, sWord)
If pos2 = 0 Then Exit Sub
v = Len(sWord)
pos3 = pos2 + v
g.Characters(Start:=pos2, Length:=pos3 - pos2).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
End Sub
```

If you can have multiple instances, update the FormatCell sub to the following:

```
Sub FormatCell(g As Range, sWord As String)
Dim pos1 As Integer, pos2 As Integer
pos1 = 1
pos2 = InStr(pos1, g.Text, sWord)
v = Len(sWord)

Do While pos2 > 0

    pos3 = pos2 + v
    g.Characters(Start:=pos2, Length:=pos3 - pos2).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)

    pos2 = InStr(pos2 + v, g.Text, sWord)

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: This is fantastic, but is it possible to make it support a variable range? For example, when I tested it and didn't have a name in Cell A3 in the keyword range, it formatted the entire selected cell. It works perfectly when the defined range in the code corresponds exactly

Comment: - to the range with names. But I'm trying to prepare for adding/deleting of names as well.

Comment: figured out a workaround, I just fill in the empty cells in my intended fixed-size namelist with "No Name". thanks anyway, nutsch!

Comment: I've put a empty check in the code. You can update accordingly.